# Firefox, make URL drag and droppable but save as Title

Tags: javascript, firefox, drag-and-drop

I have tab items on an extension, my own custom made with divs.

I make them draggable and set the drag data to:

`` e.dataTransfer.setData(`text/plain`, item.url) ``

This make the items droppable on the bookmarks bar.

If I try to make the data the title instead, it naturally doesn't drop on the bookmarks bar.

My question is, how do I make it dropped as a URL but saved as the Title instead of saved as the URL as it currently does?

Items have both `url` and `title` properties.

But I don't know how to set both on the dragged event.

Edit: Tried adding uri-list too as it is recommended:

```js
e.dataTransfer.setData(`text/plain`, item.url)
e.dataTransfer.setData(`text/uri-list`, item.url)
```

But same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I have to use x-moz-url:

```js
e.dataTransfer.setData(`text/x-moz-url`, `${item.url}\n${item.title}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs to do this in C# (like myself), here it is how you set the data so that you can drop your object back in Edge, Chrome, Firefox:

```
var dataObject = new DataObject();
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes($"{YOUR_URL}\n{YOUR_TITLE}\0");
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
dataObject.SetData("text/x-moz-url", memoryStream);
```

Don't change the encoding from Unicode, otherwise it will not work.